# Best way to get closer time to 00:00:00, 06:00:00, 12:00:00 and 18:00:00 from list

Tags: c#, algorithm, linq, date

I have a list DateTime type and I need to get the closer time to 00:00:00, 06:00:00, 12:00:00 and 18:00:00.

I am using a for loop to iterate through the list with some if conditions to get the value in between.

However, I am not sure how to get the closer value and I also wonder if there is a way to get the correct result using LINQ.

```
TimeSpan ts1 = new TimeSpan(list[i].Item1.Hour,
                            list[i].Item1.Minute, 
                            list[i].Item1.Second);

TimeSpan ts2 = new TimeSpan(list[i + 1].Item1.Hour, 
                            list[i + 1].Item1.Minute, 
                            list[i + 1].Item1.Second);

if (ts1.TotalHours < 00 && ts2.TotalHours > 00)
    Console.WriteLine("00:00:00 {0} {1} Take: {2}", ts1, ts2, ts1);
else if (ts1.TotalHours < 06 && ts2.TotalHours > 06)
    Console.WriteLine("06:00:00 {0} {1} Take: {2}", ts1, ts2, ts1);
else if (ts1.TotalHours < 12 && ts2.TotalHours > 12 )
    Console.WriteLine("12:00:00 {0} {1} Take: {2}", ts1, ts2, ts1);
else if (ts1.TotalHours < 18 && ts2.TotalHours > 18)
    Console.WriteLine("18:00:00 {0} {1} Take: {2}", ts1, ts2, ts1);
```

Output:

```
00:00:00 11:59:59 12:59:58 Take: 11:59:59
00:00:00 17:59:57 19:00:00 Take: 17:59:57
00:00:00 11:59:59 13:00:00 Take: 11:59:59
00:00:00 16:59:59 18:00:01 Take: 16:59:59
00:00:00 05:59:58 07:00:00 Take: 05:59:58
00:00:00 11:59:58 12:59:59 Take: 11:59:58
00:00:00 17:59:57 18:59:59 Take: 17:59:57
00:00:00 11:00:02 12:00:01 Take: 11:00:02
00:00:00 11:00:02 12:00:02 Take: 11:00:02
00:00:00 16:59:59 18:00:01 Take: 16:59:59
00:00:00 10:59:58 12:00:01 Take: 10:59:58
00:00:00 17:00:02 18:00:01 Take: 17:00:02
00:00:00 05:59:58 06:59:58 Take: 05:59:58
00:00:00 11:59:59 12:59:59 Take: 11:59:59
00:00:00 17:00:00 18:00:01 Take: 17:00:00
00:00:00 11:59:59 12:59:57 Take: 11:59:59
00:00:00 05:59:57 07:00:01 Take: 05:59:57
00:00:00 10:59:58 12:00:01 Take: 10:59:58
00:00:00 17:00:01 18:00:01 Take: 17:00:01
00:00:00 05:59:59 07:00:02 Take: 05:59:59
```

Comment: What datetimes do you want to compare, only the current and the next? It's not clear what you want as result.

Comment: You want the item from the list that is closest in time to any of those 4 choices?

Comment: @TimSchmelter Well, in my case I compare before and after.  if you have another option please share with me.

Comment: @DavidG that is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can substract 2 TimeSpans.
If the difference is more than 12 hours, then substract from 24 hours.

```
TimeSpan oneDay = new TimeSpan(24,0,0);
TimeSpan zero = new TimeSpan(0,0,0); //the timespan you want to compare against
TimeSpan diff1 = (ts1 - zero).Duration();
if (diff1.TotalHours >= 12) diff1 = oneDay - diff1;
TimeSpan diff2 = (ts2 - zero).Duration();
if (diff2.TotalHours >= 12) diff2 = oneDay - diff2;
TimeSpan closest = diff1 < diff2 ? ts1 : ts2
```

Comment: What if the timespan is 1 hour (1 o'clock in the night) and the datetime is  11 o'clock in the evening. The distance would be 2 hours. So if there was another `DateTime` with `TimeOfDay`=4 hour(4 o'clock in the night) the first `DateTime` should win. (if i  understood OP correctly)

Comment: @TimSchmelter I didn't think this through the first time. I hope I fixed it now.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if that is what you are trying to do, but following method returns all `DateTimes`(can be multiple with the same distance) which are nearest to a given `TimeSpan`:

```
public static IEnumerable<DateTime> GetNearestToTime(TimeSpan targetTime, params DateTime[] dates)
{
    TimeSpan negativeTarget = TimeSpan.FromHours(24) - targetTime;
    var dateInfos = dates
        .Select(dt => new
        {
            DateTime = dt,
            MinDistance = new[] { (dt.TimeOfDay - targetTime).Duration(), (dt.TimeOfDay - negativeTarget).Duration() }.Min()
        });
    var distanceLookup = dateInfos.ToLookup(x => x.MinDistance);
    TimeSpan min = distanceLookup.Min(x => x.Key);
    return distanceLookup[min].Select(x => x.DateTime);
}
```

This example show the  difficulty:

```
Target: midnight
Date1 = 2014-11-28 02:00:00
Date2 = 2014-11-27 23:00:00
```

The second `DateTime` should win since 11 o'clock in the evening(23H) is nearer to midnight than 2 o'clock in the morning.

Here's a sample with some dates and times and this edge case:

```
TimeSpan[] spans = {TimeSpan.FromHours(0), TimeSpan.FromHours(6),TimeSpan.FromHours(12),TimeSpan.FromHours(18)};
var now = DateTime.Today;  // midnight
var list = new List<DateTime> { now.AddMinutes(-99), now.AddMinutes(+100), now.AddMinutes(199), now.AddMinutes(-200) };
for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i+=2)
{
    DateTime dt1 = list[i];
    DateTime dt2 = list[i + 1];
    IEnumerable<DateTime> nearestToMidNight = GetNearestToTime(spans[0], dt1, dt2);
    Console.WriteLine("{0} nearest: {1}", spans[0], string.Join(",", nearestToMidNight));
    // and so on with the other timespans...
}
```

The output:

```
00:00:00 nearest: 27.11.2014 22:21:00
00:00:00 nearest: 27.11.2014 20:41:00
```

Comment: @doro: of course, look at "the output". You just need the method `GetNearestToTime`.

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve the value of the Ticks property and apply an offset and the modulo operator to it.
This allow for direct test of the underlying value and avoid calling properties or methods that do redundant computations over it.

```
const long TicksPerSecond = 10000000L;
const long TicksPer1Hour = TicksPerSecond * 3600;
const long TicksPer3Hours = TicksPer1Hour * 3;
const long TicksPer6Hours = TicksPer1Hour * 6;
const long TicksPerDay = TicksPer1Hour * 24;

private static long GetDiffFrom6Hours(DateTime time)
{
    return Math.Abs(TicksPer3Hours - (((time.Ticks % TicksPerDay) + TicksPer3Hours) % TicksPer6Hours));
}
```

The modulo operator will divide the 24 hours into 4 chunks matching the times of day you are comparing.
The offset allow to do only 1 comparison instead of 4.

To sort your list through Linq you simply do:

```
var list2 = list.OrderBy(item => GetDiffFrom6Hours(item.Item1));
```

Regards,
Daniele.

Answer (score 0):

I went through all the answers and I have to say that the one from Dennis_E is the best and simplest.  However, I simplified it even more and for the case of 00:00:00 I used the following code.  The same logic can be used for 06:00:00, 12:00:00 and 18:00:00.  In addition, would be great if could be possible to find a solution using LINQ.

```
TimeSpan ts00 = new TimeSpan(00, 00, 00);
TimeSpan diff1 = (ts1 - ts00).Duration();
TimeSpan diff2 = (ts2 - ts00).Duration();
TimeSpan closest = diff1 < diff2 ? ts1 : ts2;
Console.WriteLine("00:00:00 Take: {0}\n\n", closest);
```